# Why is retrofit response list null?

Tags: java, android, list, retrofit

I'm developing an android app which uses Retrofit to make API call. I'm trying to fetch records from a table named "reception" with only one column `rClose`. The API call responds well in POSTMAN test. However, when I handle the response in my fragment code to get the response length (size) of the `closeList` the code runs with no error but the app crashes in run time and I get the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomerHomeFragment extends Fragment{

    private List<Close> closeList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_customer, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Call<CloseResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getCloses();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CloseResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CloseResponse> call, Response<CloseResponse> response) {

                closeList = response.body().getCloses();


                int count = closeList.size();
                if(count < 1){
                    showFoodsInRecyclerView();
                }else{


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CloseResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });



    }

}
```

**Api.java**

```
  @GET("allclose")
    Call<CloseResponse> getCloses();
```

Close.java

```
public class Close {

    private String rClose;

    public Close(String rClose) {
        this.rClose = rClose;

    }


    public String getRClose() {
        return rClose;
    }

}
```

**CloseResponse.java**

```
public class CloseResponse {

    private boolean error;
    private List<Close> closes;

    public CloseResponse(boolean error, List<Close> closes) {
        this.error = error;
        this.closes = closes;
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return error;
    }

    public List<Close> getCloses() {
        return closes;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2019-08-24 19:14:11.817 3718-3718/com.nikappzaar.app.foodtakeout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikappzaar.app.foodtakeout, PID: 3718
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.nikappzaar.app.foodtakeout.fragments.CustomerHomeFragment$1.onResponse(CustomerHomeFragment.java:77)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

The error is in the following code line:

```
int count = closeList.size();
```

I did some research on `NullPointerException` but I don't know why is the response list "null", while the same approach on other tables of my database is working well! What am I doing wrong?

Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your logcat here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information.Also tell us what line causes the error.

Comment: First,You should add this code in onResponse: if (response.isSuccessful()) {....}...............Then if(response.body()!=null){..........}

Comment: Did you added addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) in your retrofit client builder?

Comment: I did same as above for my other tables and got response well and showed the list in recyclerviews. But I don't know why it is not working here.

Comment: I don't think your code truly runs "without error". Your onFailure block isn't implemented, so your silently ignoring when requests fail. In any case, you'd get null list if the response cannot be parsed, so can you please show the output you're getting from the API?

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize List with new in this fragment **CustomerHomeFragment**.
Change this line private List closeList; with 
private List closeList = new ArrayList();
It will solve your error.

Comment: That doesn't stop `response.body().getCloses()` from possibly being null

Comment: Have you tried to debug you app? Are you getting data in closeList.

Comment: It's not my app. I'm just saying that initializing the field wouldn't fix the shown stacktrace

Comment: @cricket_007 is right. This doesn't fix the problem. I think the problem is that I'm not getting the data in closeList.